forecast payment terms by calculating payment by month and stop calculating on need date
I'm trying to forecast payments into the future and calculate the cost per month from the order date to need date and stop calculating the month of the need date. I'm tracking multiple orders under one big project to track/forecast baseline expenditures, and want to project forecast into dates that haven't been available yet (ie. 2026, 2029).
Calculated cost per month =  Item Cost / Months till need date
Data Table



Order Num
Order Date
Need Date
Total Item Cost
Months till Need Date
Calculated Cost Per Month




Order 1-1
7/1/2024
12/1/2024
$650
5
$130


Order 1-2
8/1/2024
10/1/2024
$1200
2
$600


Order 1-3
9/1/2024
9/1/2024
$300
0
$300



Desired Output: I want to receive the following output of total calculations per month on all orders - I'll be viewing the data as a line graph.



Months
7/1/2024
8/1/2024
9/1/2024
10/1/2024
11/1/2024
12/1/2024




Order 1-1 Cost
130
130
130
130
130
130


Order 1-2 Cost
0
600
600
600
0
0


Order 1-3 Cost
0
0
300
0
0
0


Total Cost
130
730
1030
730
130
130



I tried comparing it to another table in PowerBI, but making another table in SQL may be better/more efficient, but I'm not sure how to project the values. I am also not sure when to cut off the payment so it stops calculating cost at and after the need date.
Really appreciate any time or help towards this question - thank you.

please post sql code with sample data. CREATE TABLE... INSERT INTO...

If you have a calendar table/virtual table you can generate the rows between order date and end of projection date and then pivot that into a table where row becomes monthly columns

Here are the links for your reference :- Calendar Table, Pivot

you can try data transform in PQ
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45W8i9KSS1SMNQ1VNJRMtc31DcyMDIBMg2NEGwzUwMgaaoUq4NQbgQUsUBSboCs1QCk3ghFvTFQxBKhBolpDFZtoBQbCwA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Order Num" = _t, #"Order Date" = _t, #"Need Date" = _t, #"Total Item Cost" = _t, #"Months till Need Date" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Order Num", type text}, {"Order Date", type date}, {"Need Date", type date}, {"Total Item Cost", Int64.Type}, {"Months till Need Date", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each {Number.From([Order Date])..Number.From([Need Date])}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Custom",{{"Custom", type date}}),
    #"Calculated Start of Month" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type1",{{"Custom", Date.StartOfMonth, type date}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Calculated Start of Month", {"Order Num", "Custom"}, {{"Total Item", each List.Average([Total Item Cost]), type nullable text}, {"Month", each List.Average([Months till Need Date]), type nullable number}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Cost Per Month", each if [Month] =0 then  [Total Item] else [Total Item]/[Month]),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Total Item", "Month"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns", {{"Custom", type text}}, "zh-CN"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns", {{"Custom", type text}}, "zh-CN")[Custom]), "Custom", "Cost Per Month"),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Pivoted Column",null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"2024/7/1", "2024/8/1", "2024/9/1", "2024/10/1", "2024/11/1", "2024/12/1"})
in
    #"Replaced Value"


